# how to pass null value to database from cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to save NULL in database for column while textbox is empty.
Here is my code,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RedirectUris", ((RedirectUris.Text == "") ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : RedirectUris.Text));
```

where RedirectUris is textbox id.
 In this scenario database is saving empty value not as NULL.
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RedirectUris", string.IsNullOrEmpty(RedirectUris.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : RedirectUris.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RedirectUris", 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(RedirectUris.Text) 
        ? (object)DBNull.Value : 
        RedirectUris.Text);
```

Might make sense to check if the value of the textbox is null or empty

Comment: It is better because here we do'nt need to create new SqlParameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the short format:

```
// update
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseTimeDays", responseTimeDays ?? Convert.DBNull);

// insert
new SqlParameter("@ResponseTimeDays", cinfo.ResponseTimeDays ?? Convert.DBNull)
```